# dynamic parameter ngrx selector

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx

i'm a bit struggling here
i have the following selector

```
export const selectMoMenuInfoByIdDynamic = createSelector(
selectMoMenuState,
state => (meId: string) => {
let currentMenu: MoMenu
console.log(state.MoMenuItems)
currentMenu = state.MoMenuItems.find(element => {
return element.ME_ID === meId
})
return currentMenu
}
)
```

but can't get it to work when i call it with

```
const moMenu = this.store.pipe(
select(selectMoMenuInfoByIdDynamic),
map(res => res(meId))
)
console.log(moMenu)
```

Any idea for me ?

Would be huge help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to create a parameterized selector, each have a use case.
See my post [Parameterized selectors](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/parameterized-selectors) for more info.

```
export const getCount = () => createSelector(
  getCounterValue,
  (counter, props) => counter * props.multiply,
)

// in components:

this.counter = this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.getCount, { multiply: 2 }))
```

---

```
export const selectCustomer = (id: string) =>
  createSelector(
    selectCustomers,
    customers => customers[id],
  )

// in component

this.customer = store.pipe(select(customers.selectCustomer('47')))
```

Comment: I did follow this guide https://blog.angularindepth.com/ngrx-parameterized-selector-e3f610529f8

Comment: Thanks man it's working i just didnt think about subscribe to my observable ....